# Showing Modal when text is clicked inside marker popup

Tags: leaflet

I am customizing the Bootleaf template, what I want to do is when I click the description text the modal will appear. I am using Leaflet. I already tried the code below but nothing happens when I click the "description" text.

[image]

This is the modal

```
<div class="modal fade" id="descriptionModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button
          type="button"
          class="close"
          data-dismiss="modal"
          aria-hidden="true"
        >
          &times;
        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Description Title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Description here...</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">
          Close
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is the script to open the modal

```
$("#description-btn").click(function () {
 $("#descriptionModal").modal("show");
 $(".navbar-collapse.in").collapse("hide");
 return false;
});
```

And this is the script for the marker

```
var buildingLayer = L.geoJson(null);
var buildings = L.geoJson(null, {
  pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
    return L.marker(latlng, {
      icon: L.icon({
        iconUrl: "assets/img/campus.png",
        iconSize: [28, 28],
        iconAnchor: [12, 28],
        popupAnchor: [0, -25],
      }),
      title: feature.properties.NAME,
      riseOnHover: true,
    });
  },
  onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
    if (feature.properties) {
      layer
        .bindPopup(
          "<p><b><center>" +
            feature.properties.NAME +
            "</center></b></p>" +
            "<center><img src='" +
            feature.properties.PIC +
            "' style='width:150px;height:50x;'></img></center> " +
            "</br><a href='#' data-toggle='collapse' data-target='.navbar-collapse.in' id='description-btn'>" +
            feature.properties.DESC +
            "</a>" +
            "</br><a href='#'>" +
            feature.properties.ENTER +
            "</a>"
        )
        .openPopup();
      buildingSearch.push({
        name: layer.feature.properties.NAME,
        address: layer.feature.properties.ADDRESS1,
        source: "Buildings",
        id: L.stamp(layer),
        lat: layer.feature.geometry.coordinates[1],
        lng: layer.feature.geometry.coordinates[0],
      });
    }
  },
});
$.getJSON("data/building.geojson", function (data) {
  buildings.addData(data);
  map.addLayer(buildingLayer);
});
```

Comment: Any errors in the browser debugger console?

Comment: I don't receive any errors, I don't know what the problem is. Showing the modal works on the topnav bar but not working in the marker popup.

Comment: Which version of Leaflet are you using? BootLeaf demo at https://bryanmcbride.com/bootleaf/ uses ages old Leaflet 0.7.7.

Comment: I'm using the exact same version, 0.7.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Script to set click processing for `description-btn` element does not work because element does not exist yet at the time of script run, since it's created when popup is opened.

Simple workaround for this is to attach click processing function directly to `description-btn` element, and this function can then open modal dialog.

Relevant part of the code could then look something like this:

```
function openModal() {
  $("#descriptionModal").modal("show");
  $(".navbar-collapse.in").collapse("hide");
}

.
.
.

onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
  if (feature.properties) {
    layer
      .bindPopup(
        "<p><b><center>" +
          feature.properties.NAME +
          "</center></b></p>" +
          "<center><img src='" +
          feature.properties.PIC +
          "' style='width:150px;height:50x;'></img></center> " +
          "</br><a href='#' onclick='openModal()' data-toggle='collapse' data-target='.navbar-collapse.in' id='description-btn'>" +
          feature.properties.DESC +
          "</a>" +
          "</br><a href='#'>" +
          feature.properties.ENTER +
          "</a>"
      )
      .openPopup();
    buildingSearch.push({
      name: layer.feature.properties.NAME,
      address: layer.feature.properties.ADDRESS1,
      source: "Buildings",
      id: L.stamp(layer),
      lat: layer.feature.geometry.coordinates[1],
      lng: layer.feature.geometry.coordinates[0],
    });
  }
},
```